# Keep some cookies only if hitting some specific controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.MVC 5 application where one section(***by section I mean a website section, does not mean to be a specific area or sth***) has some fields stored in cookies and they are used only in that section. But for some reason I have to invalidate the cookies as soon as the user leaves this section and goes somewhere else, so, if he returns back to this section later at some point he does not have old cookies but new ones will be generated. I was thinking to create somehow an attribute and mark all controllers of this section with an id. Then at the base class I will check if the controller has that specific id, in that case I don`t do anything otherwise will invalidate cookies. But this is not a good solution I guess because every request made to other sections will try to invalidate some cookies which is not good(**waste of resources!**). Is there any proper way of doing this in general ?

All controllers inherit from a BaseController if this helps.

I know this seems like something is wrong in the design but can not be helped since its old code being migrated to ASP.NET MVC and for this case really can not do anything else.

So here is the situation in code:

```
public class BaseController : Controller 
{
    //OnActionExecuted check if controller has Id = 1, dont do anything else invalidate cookies
}

[GiveSomeId(1)]
public class CookieController : BaseController {}

public class OtherController : BaseController { }
```

Comment: Any specific reason you want to keep the state in a cookie?

Comment: Basically this section can be accessed from Admin as a simple user(In that case I operate on currentUser.Id where I get the Admin id). But if he chooses to go to X user profile then I need to operate as (X.Id). So, I store X user id in a cookie. Then later I ask if the cookie has value get the id and operate on that one otherwise we know Admin is using this section as simple user, so he is at his profile and I user Admin Id. at the end its like this `var id  = CookieService.HasValue("MyCookie") ? CookieService.GetValue("MyCookie") : User.Id;`.

Comment: One option would be to use params in each action but this would make the code ugly and easy to be changed from the url string

Comment: Sounds like an impersonation feature. If that is the case, you should try to implement impersonation at the level of the authentication middleware. Always a tricky feature and can create a security issue if implemented incorrectly.